# Entity Framework Mapping Foreign Key with Collections and TPH Inhehritance

Tags: frameworks, foreign-keys, mapping, entity, tph

I Try to map this simple model with TPH inheritance :

```
    public abstract class Master {
    public long Id {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

public class MasterA : Master {
    public string FieldA {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class MasterB : Master {
    public string FieldB {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public abstract class Detail {
    public long Id {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public long MasterId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Master Master {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String CommonDetailInfo {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class DetailA : Detail {
    public MasterA MasterA {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string SpecificA {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class DetailB : Detail {
    public MasterB MasterB {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string SpecificB {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Mapping is done with fluent Notation Like this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().ToTable("TestMaster");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().Property(m => m.Id)
                                     .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().Map<MasterA>(m => m.Requires("MasterType").HasValue("A"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().Map<MasterB>(m => m.Requires("MasterType").HasValue("B"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Detail>().ToTable("TestDetail");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Detail>().Property(d => d.Id)
                                     .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Detail>().HasKey(d => d.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Detail>().Map<DetailA>(m => m.Requires("DetailType").HasValue("A"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Detail>().Map<DetailB>(m => m.Requires("DetailType").HasValue("B"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Details)
            .WithRequired(d => d.Master)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.MasterId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

If I let EF create my database, two fields are added in TestDetail table :

```
MasterA_Id
MasterB_Id
```

But these two fields are always Null and redundant because MasterId field on base Dteail Class do the same job ?

If I remove these fields from database and try to get Details on a master record like this :

```
  foreach (var detail in master.Details) {...}
```

An Exception is raised : Invalid ColumnName MasterA_Id, MasterB_Id when I access "Details" property.

What I'm doing wrong ?
How can I map this model in TPH mode without having these two fields in database ?

Thanks for your help.